# The 'queries' variable is already used as an 'array expression'

Tags: php, foreach, phpstorm

I am importing countries from an API like so

```
public function importAPI()
{

    $url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/';
    $json = file_get_contents($url);

    $countries = [];

    $queries = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach ($queries as $item['name']){
        foreach ($queries as $country){
             $countries[] = $country['name'];
        }
    }
    return $countries;
}
```

I am getting the error mentioned in the title

> The 'queries' variable is already used as an 'array expression'

And I don't quite understand it, since the result that I return is correct.

Is this something that I need to worry about or have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your end goal appears to be to obtain an array of country names, you can just use the following:

```
public function importAPI()
{
    $url  = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/';
    $json = json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );

    $countries = [ ];

    foreach( $json as $country )
    {
        $countries[] = $country->name;
    }

    return $countries;
}
```

Comment: Hi, with this i get only 250 results, with the function above i get all 62500 results.

Comment: Here are only half of my results(i didn't copy all) https://pastebin.com/0NvJ65F5

Comment: Because your current code is looping multiple times. Check your array. There are multiple instances of `Afghanistan`. Please look at the array returned by the API call, there are only 250 entries.

Comment: "_i get all 62500 results_" 62500 countries in the world?